# How to get the historical components of the stock index constituents?

Tags: historical-data, market-indexes, historical-analysis

Does anyone know where to get the historical components of the stock indexes (NASDAQ,FTSE,SENSEX)? I want to see which companies existed in stock indexes in 1980 and to see which companies made it to 1990 or any other period.

Comment: WRDS via University affiliation.

Comment: Can you give url?

Comment: https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/connect/ You need to ask your University for details. Usually it takes a correct IP and a university email.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_components_of_the_Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average and similar?

Comment: @barrycarter Helpful. But I want to know weight in the index and constituents of multiple indexes(international).

Comment: Have you tried contacting the index maintainers directly? See also http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9523/components-of-an-index-in-a-specific-date

Comment: @barrycarter No. Will it be easy?

Comment: @shravan The publishers at S&P Global, which also owns the Dow Jones series of indexes provide the historical components in electronic / database format for a fee.  A business school library may grant you access to S&P's index products in digital and print formats.